# webcam stopped working after new OS system and motherboard install

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam

I bought recently a webcam https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B087Q85S47/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 which use UVC HD Camera drivers dated 21/06/2006 Version 10.0.19041.488 with Digital Signer Microsoft Windows.

This camera was working perfectly fine before the change of hardware and having to reinstall from scratch the OS Windows 10 (I have a legit key copy).

Not only this camera stopped working, but even my HD C920 started to have trouble, luckily I could control that camera by launching an application of the logitech that seems helps to render it fine. But for the other being a generic product, it just doesn't work.

I tried to contact windows support and ask for help, and they weren't helpful.

I tried all the things that normally is needed to try like uninstall and reinstall drivers, manually try to install drivers instead than automatically, using windows update for the latest drivers, and trying to as well changing USB ports, giving all camera authorization in the private settings and as well trying various software. The problem is absolutely the same.

The video or doesn't work, or if it renders it is completely crazily glitchy, if I try to reduce the resolution it renders better, but the pixel morphs and it still not working correctly.

I am 100% sure that the problem it is the driver that windows has, and I have no idea how to test for anything different.

Any other suggestion that I could try? I am a streamer and I really wanted a second cam for my stream to work.